# Critical dependency warning when using react-pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to display a pdf on a react application and i get the following warning:

> /node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
>   Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Vscode tells me this under the import function.

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pdf'

Already tried running `npm install`, `npm install react-pdf` and reinstalling the package

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document } from 'react-pdf';
import sample from 'file location'
export default class viewer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Document
                    file={sample}
                    onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                >
                </Document>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Displays:

> "Failed to load PDF file" in the browser

Comment: Is it a typescript project you are working on? Because the missing declaration file is a typescript warning. The first warning is from the library itself, so it is properly installed but maybe broken.

Comment: It would be also good to know if you are on a `create-react-app` project. Then maybe this will help you: ```import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
 pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;```

Comment: @hyde yea its a typescript project. Are you saying that it may be a react-pdf issue?

Comment: @hyde  yea its a react-app. i'll try this

Comment: If its a typescript project you should also try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-pdf` to get the definitions. But I dont know if react-pdf has types at all.

Comment: I ended up scrapping it and just using an iframe. It got the job done

Comment: If you have the time to provide an example repo on git I will take the time to solve it ;) Cannot be that you have to fallback to an IFrame. Any further communication better go to a chat.

Answer (score 0):

This code will display your pdf file, but issue will display in IDE console.

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

In my case I'm using webpack 4 and it's not supportted yet.
If you build project it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My full workaround.
Create a file at the root called config-overrides.js and it should contain the following:
module.exports = function override(config) {
config.module.rules[0].parser.requireEnsure = true
return config
};

After that npm i react-app-rewired to you app and change your build function in package.json to read react-app-rewired build/react-app-rewired start.
That should do it for now.